# Тип веб сервиса

Tags: java, xml, servlet, веб-сервер

Есть веб-сервис, а точнее сервлет, который принимает только HTTP POST запросы. URL обращения к сервису один и представляет из себя ссылку на сервлет, к примеру: 
http:localhost:8080/ApplicationName/ServletName

Запросы отличаются друг от друга только XML-ом внутри HTTP Body. То есть весь функционал веб-сервиса заключён внутри тела сообщения и представляет из себя обычный XML вида:

```
<CustomProtocol>
<MessageData>
//some tags
</MessageData>
</CustomProtocol>
```

Теперь собственно вопрос: что это за стандарт/архитектура/стиль веб сервиса? Я так понимаю это ни SOAP, ни REST.

В дополнение: насколько актуальны подобные вер-сервисы? Если я правильно понимаю это устаревшая технология.

Comment: Почему не SOAP?

Comment: Это просто веб-сервис, использующий XML для сериализации данных.